# Google Earth Engine is failing to parse this custom WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Projection: The CRS of a map projection could not be parsed. (Error code: 3)
```

when trying to export google earth engine imagery to an albers equal area conic projection with a WGS84 datum. This CRS is used by LCMAP, and I would like to export images that align with that projection to save myself some post-processing time.

What is wrong with this WKT?

```
var aea_wgs84 = '\
  PROJCRS["Albers", \
  BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84", \
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", \
  ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378140,298.256999999996, \
  LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]], \
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0, \
  ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]], \
  ID["EPSG",4326]], \
  CONVERSION["Albers Equal Area", \
  METHOD["Albers Equal Area", \
  ID["EPSG",9822]], \
  PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",23, \
  ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433], \
  ID["EPSG",8821]], \
  PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-96, \
  ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433], \
  ID["EPSG",8822]], \
  PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",29.5, \
  ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433], \
  ID["EPSG",8823]], \
  PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45.5, \
  ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433], \
  ID["EPSG",8824]], \
  PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0, \
  LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], \
  ID["EPSG",8826]], \
  PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0, \
  LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], \
  ID["EPSG",8827]]], \
  CS[Cartesian,2], \
  AXIS["easting",east, \
  ORDER[1], \
  LENGTHUNIT["metre",1, \
  ID["EPSG",9001]]], \
  AXIS["northing",north, \
  ORDER[2], \
  LENGTHUNIT["metre",1, \
  ID["EPSG",9001]]]]'
```

Comment: Not sure it makes a difference, but WKT1 uses "PROJCS" and WKT2 uses "PROJCRS":  https://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc17/tech-workshops/tw_2588-212.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is off from what Earth Engine is expecting when creating an `ee.Projection` object. There are extra unnecessary parameters and the name/data provided are off from what is expected. Here is a correctly formatted WKT string that should give you the desired projection:

```js
var aea_wgs84 = '
PROJCS["Projection = Albers Conical Equal Area", \
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", \
    DATUM["WGS_1984", \
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], \
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], \
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], \
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], \
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST], \
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], \
  PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"], \
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", -96.0], \
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 23.0], \
  PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1", 29.5], \
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], \
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], \
  PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2", 45.5], \
  UNIT["m", 1.0], \
  AXIS["x", EAST], \
  AXIS["y", NORTH]] \
'
```

Alternatively, if there is a dataset on Earth Engine that already has that projection (in this case the NLCD data has the same projection), then you can pull it from there. See example:

```js
// load in a NLCD image with desired projection
var image = ee.ImageCollection("USGS/NLCD_RELEASES/2019_REL/NLCD").first()

// extract projection from image
var proj = image.projection()

// print WKT from projection
print(proj.wkt())
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Kel's answer, if there isn't an existing dataset in Earth Engine with the projection you want to use, create your own raster with the projection you want and then upload it as an asset to GEE. Then load the image asset in a script and use:

```
// extract projection from image
var proj = image.projection()

// print WKT from projection
print(proj.wkt())
```